# Creating Many-Element Form Field in Django

Tags: django, forms, field

I want to allow users to fill out information about themselves upon sign up. A couple examples would be what languages they know, and what business skills they have. I want them to be able to type in skills like "Finance", press enter, and have it added to their list. Then on the same page they can type in "Accounting" and also enter it, without having to press a submit button each time.

How do I create a field that users can add multiple elements to? The functionality I'm thinking of is similar to LinkedIn's "skills" section, where you can add as many things as you want but also delete ones you already have.

I'd like to be able to query my database and match to any of the words in these fields.

Here is an example of what I would like it to look like after a user has edited and submitted, just to give you an idea of what I'm talking about.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I supose that the words have to be stored in DB; then you need to define a ManytoMany field and use an adequate widget in frontend.

For Django exists some projects with a similar functionality: [django-tagging](https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-tagging) , [django-taggit](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit).

To frontend, you need something like this: [tag-it](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it)

This would be useful too: [django-taggit-labels](https://github.com/bennylope/django-taggit-labels)